# FindWindow: FindControl from real control name at runtime

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, debugging, findwindow

When we compile an executable with Delphi or Visual Studio, it is possible to include "debug informations" in executable.
What i want to do is compile an executable with those debug informations.
Then, from a second program, il need to interact with first program. I need to find text boxes and other controls. It is possible to do that with FindWindow API. But i want to access debug informations in order to find control from its real name.
Do you know how should i do ?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use UI Automation?

Comment: Thanks for your Answer but the program is written in Delphi. No Microsoft...

Comment: That's fine. What makes you think that UI Automation is only for ms tools?

Comment: You don't need to compile the first app with debug info in order to interact with it from a second app. Nor would doing so help you in this situation anyway.  A VCL control's `Name` is not accessible across process boundaries, unless you resort to using `ReadProcessMemory()`.

Comment: Ok i will have a look to "UI Automation". But for now i really need to read memory and find each control with its name. Can you tell me more about ReadProcessMemory ?
Thanks